# How can I make available document.all in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

Looks like document.all method is not available in IE11. So what is best way to make available or what is alternative of that?

Comment: `document.all` has been obsolete for like two decades at this point. Try `document.getElementById('elementID')`

Comment: thanks @NiettheDarkAbsol for input. Sorry I didn't get a chance to revisit this question. this is some banking legacy application which was written few decade back. Which is working only in IE compatibility mode. So I am making this browser compatible and work in native mode...so looking for some native solution so that I don't have to touch hundred of files. this is how I fixed this broken peace , I redefine document.all, which making us of document.querySelector and document.querySelectorAll internally.

Answer (score 1):

This is not standard and should not be used.
As per MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document#

As per Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx#docmode

Use `document.getElementById` instead

Comment: document.all can't be replaced with any of the native api...document.all accept name and id both and getElementById accept just "id".